# Installing modules in npm is giving error message missing wide-align module

Tags: javascript

Trying to install -- npm crypto-js --> get the error : "Cannot find module 'wide-align'" -- also can't run `npm init` / same error when trying to install anything -- any ideas anyone ??

Comment: running  'npm -v'  -->  returns the same message - "Cannot find module 'wide-align'"

Comment: Must be some missing dependency. Try install wide-align package with 'npm install wide-align'

Comment: Tried that --> Same error when I try to install anything. Tried to run "npm install -g npm"  -- same error : "Cannot find module 'wide-align'". I thought maybe need to start all over but how do I do that ??

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Trying to do that but don't know how -- tried to open a PNG file in paint and copy and paste it into this box but that doesn't work. How do I post an image file / PNG?

Answer (score -2):

1. Right-click on Start or Windows icon --> Search --> Type command prompt.
2. Right-click on Command Prompt and select 'Run as Administrator".

   [just like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXhyP.png)
3. Enter the below command: **chkdsk /f h:** --> Press Enter. (Replace h: with the drive letter that you install node js)